# stopping threads that run indefinitely

Tags: java, multithreading, interrupt, producer-consumer, interrupted-exception

I have been trying to implement the producer consumer pattern. If both producer and consumer are running indefinitely how should one try to stop them?

I have been trying to test the status of `isInterrupted()` but the following code does not guarantee all threads to stop.

```
public class Monitor {

    private int value;
    private boolean readable = false;

    public synchronized void setVal(int value) {
        while (readable) {
            try {
                this.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            this.readable = true;
            this.value = value;
            this.notifyAll();
        }
    }

    public synchronized int getVal() {
        while (!readable) {
            try {
                this.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            this.readable = false;
            this.notifyAll();
        }
        return this.value;
    }
}
```

The producer class looks like this:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Producer implements Runnable {

    private Monitor monitor;
    private Random r = new Random();
    private String name;

    public Producer(Monitor m) {monitor = m;}

    public void run() {
        name = Thread.currentThread().getName();
        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            int value = r.nextInt(1000);
            monitor.setVal(value);
            System.out.println("PRODUCER: " + name + " set " + value);
        }
        System.out.println("PRODUCER: " + name + " interrupted");
    }
}
```

The consumer

```
public class Consumer implements Runnable {

    private Monitor monitor;
    private String name;

    public Consumer(Monitor m) {monitor = m;}

    public void run() {
        name = Thread.currentThread().getName();
        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            int value = monitor.getVal();
            System.out.println("CONSUMER: " + name + " got " + value);
        }
        System.out.println("CONSUMER: " + name + " interrupted");
    }
}
```

And the main:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final int n = 2;
        Monitor m = new Monitor();

        Thread[] producers = new Thread[n];
        Thread[] consumers = new Thread[n];

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            producers[i] = new Thread(new Producer(m));
            producers[i].start();
            consumers[i] = new Thread(new Consumer(m));
            consumers[i].start();
        }

//        try {
//            Thread.sleep(1);
//        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            producers[i].interrupt();
            consumers[i].interrupt();
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following results

```
PRODUCER: Thread-0 set 917
CONSUMER: Thread-1 got 917
PRODUCER: Thread-2 set 901
PRODUCER: Thread-0 set 29
CONSUMER: Thread-3 interrupted
CONSUMER: Thread-1 got 29
CONSUMER: Thread-1 interrupted
PRODUCER: Thread-2 set 825
...program hangs
```

and

```
PRODUCER: Thread-0 set 663
CONSUMER: Thread-1 got 663
PRODUCER: Thread-0 set 129
CONSUMER: Thread-1 got 129
PRODUCER: Thread-2 set 93
PRODUCER: Thread-2 interrupterd
CONSUMER: Thread-3 interrupted
PRODUCER: Thread-0 set 189
PRODUCER: Thread-0 interrupterd
CONSUMER: Thread-1 got 129
...program hangs
```

etc...

There is clearly something wrong. Why am I not registering the calls the `interrupt` on a consistent basis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is perhaps surprising that catching an `InterruptedException` *does not* mean that the interrupted flag is set on the thread.

The interrupted flag and `InterruptedException` are two completely separate ways of indicating that an interrupt has occurred:

- You can throw an `InterruptedException` without first checking whether the thread has been interrupted.
- You can set the interrupted flag without catching an `InterruptedException`.

In order to correctly preserve the fact that the thread was interrupted (or, at least, that an `InterruptedException` was caught), you should explicitly re-interrupt the thread in your catch block:

```
//  ...
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
  Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
  break;
}
// ...
```

This sets the interrupted flag, so your `isInterrupted()` check should now work.

Comment: This is why the `consumer` and `producer` class loops work then? as I test for the flag in the while loop instead of using `while (true)`...

Comment: No. There is nowhere in your loop where you can detect the interrupted flag in the loop reliably. The reason is that the code throwing the `InterruptedException` might be implemented with code like `if (Thread.interrupted()) { throw new InterruptedException(); }` - and if you read the javadoc for [`interrupted()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupted()), you will see that it checks *and clears* the flag.

Comment: (My comment relates to your previous comment, that you edited).

Comment: Sorry about the edit... Hmmm... then does this mean that the producer and consumer loops are ok **only** because there are no `InterrupedException`'s being thrown?